# Magento 2 Checkout session lost custom data

Tags: magento-2.1, session, checkoutsession

I have created Custom checkout session in controller :

```
public function execute()
{
     $productData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

     $this->_checkoutSession->setData("product", $productData);
     ...
     ...
}
```

And access that session in block but which close tab and open it again the lost its data.
Even in few time session lost data.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of use Magento Checkout sessions I use php checkout:

```
$_SESSION['product'][$productData];
```

Because when I use magento session into block it destroy when I refresh.

Comment: magento 2 does not allow to use that... when you submit module to marketplace it will show error, so better to use other

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
public function __construct(........,\Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession,......)
{
  $this->_session = $backendSession;
}

public function execute()
{
     $productData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

     $this->_session->setData("product", $productData);
     ...
     ...
}
```

Hope it will work for you, for me working.

Comment: I did same bro, that code mentioned in question also.

Comment: i did not use checkout session please check my code

Comment: Thanks for response but i tried all magento sessions

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue. We are not getting order data or custom data from checkout session. This does not happen always but randomly. Please suggest what can be done.